# Is there a way to a prevent a String from being interpolated in Swift?

Tags: string, swift, logging, string-interpolation

I'm experimenting around the idea of a simple logger that would look like this:

```
log(constant: String, _ variable: [String: AnyObject]? = nil)
```

Which would be used like this:

```
log("Something happened", ["error": error])
```

However I want to prevent misuse of the constant/variable pattern like the following:

```
log("Something happened: \(error)") // `error` should be passed in the `variable` argument
```

Is there a way to make sure that `constant` wasn't constructed with a string interpolation?

Comment: `pod CocoaLumberjack`

Comment: @nhgrif Thanks for the suggestion. My question is not really tied to a logging context though, it's more about string plain literals and interpolation and whether those can be distinguished.

Comment: I know.  I'm just heavily, heavily recommending against yet another logging library...

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`StaticString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_StaticString_Structure/index.html) instead of `String`:

```
func log(constant: StaticString, _ variable: [String: AnyObject]? = nil) {
    // You can retrieve `String` from `StaticString`
    let msg = constant.stringValue
}

let foo = 1
log("test \(foo)") // -> error: cannot invoke 'log' with an argument list of type '(String)'
```